# Divi: how to change button apperance on click another one

Tags: jquery, css, divi

I have these 2 buttons on Divi builder. My aim: when I click on "button 2", this one becomes in orange and "button 1" becomes in grey, and the opposite.

[image]

On Button setup (from the builder), I set empty Link field for these 2 buttons. BUT when I click, my current web page is reloaded...

I've added this script into Divi Theme Option > Integration > header, just to catch the click on the first button:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".button1").on("click", function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Button clicked");
        });
    });
});
```

And for this Button 1, I set the CSS Class:

[image]

The result: no click is catched...

Could you help me guys to do my final aim please?

Comment: @freedomn-m: sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Please include the HTML for your `<button>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one out. Ignore the CSS, the main part is jQuery code.

The variable `buttons` contains the group of elements on which you want to add this feature.

The "click" event handler is added, and rest is easy to understand.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var buttons = $(".button1").siblings().addBack();
    buttons.on("click", function() {
      $(this).addClass('orange').removeClass('gray');
      buttons.not($(this)).addClass('gray').removeClass('orange');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

div {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: #eee;
  display: inline;
  cursor: default;
}

.orange {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  color: orange;
}

.gray {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button1">Button1</div>
<div class="button2">Button2</div>
<div class="button3">Button3</div>
<div class="button4">Button4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead,

I created two class orange and gray for border style

```
button.orange{
  border:2px solid orange;
}
button.gray{
  border:2px solid gray;
}
```

Then, button click event add class gray and remove it class orange and also add siblings to orange color and remove it's gray color.

```
$(this).removeClass("orange").removeClass("gray");
$(this).addClass("gray");
$(this).siblings().addClass("orange").removeClass("gray");
```

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("button").on("click", function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).removeClass("gray").removeClass("orange");
            $(this).addClass("orange");
            $(this).siblings().addClass("gray").removeClass("orange");
        });
    });
});
```

```css
button{
  border:none;
  padding:10px 20px;
  border-radius:8px;
  color:#111;
}
button.orange{
  border:2px solid orange;
  color:orange;
}
button.gray{
  border:2px solid gray;
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button1">Button1</button>
<button class="button2">Button2</button>
```

Comment: Please try this `$("button").on("click", function(){}` to each button clicked this function EXECUTED.

Comment: The click is listen (works fine now), but the color doesn't change on both buttons

Answer (score 0):

I've added this script:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        
        $(".button1").on("click", function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".button2").removeClass('orange').addClass('gray');
            $(".button1").removeClass('gray').addClass('orange');
            $('.price').text("MOIS");
        });
        
        $(".button2").on("click", function(){
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".button1").removeClass('orange').addClass('gray');
            $(".button2").removeClass('gray').addClass('orange');
            $('.price').text("ANNÉE");
        });
    });
});
```

And this custom CSS:

```
button.orange{
  border:1px solid #efa100;
}
button.gray{
  border:1px solid #8f8f8f;
}
```

The click on buttons works fine ("price" text is updated successfuly), BUT the button apparence doesn't change...

Comment: Try changing your CSS to be just the class name (`.orange{..}` and not `button.orange{..}`) That's looking for a button element with the class of "orange". There's nothing wrong with that but if you have divs instead of buttons it's not going to work. Also make sure the orange/gray styles are AFTER the CSS that defines the button look since you want to override it.

Comment: I've already tried with just the class name, and it doesn't work too.

Comment: I didn't define button element into my CSS. The button is build with Divi Builder.

Comment: Can you show the HTML that JQuery is acting on and the full CSS for the buttons? I'm guessing that there's either a CSS specificity issue or a reference issue in your jQuery but it's hard to find that stuff without more context.